# JS query to Jira REST API works fine but similar query to Jira Agile REST API fails

Tags: javascript, rest, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-agile

I'm trying to fetch data from my Jira Cloud instance through the Jira and Jira Agile REST APIs using JavaScript in a browser. Queries to Jira REST API work fine but identical queries to Jira **Agile** REST API keep failing with the response

```
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401.
```

I'm using Basic Authentication with user ID and an API token obtained from Jira. With cURL and ARC, I'm able to successfully retrieve data both from the Jira REST API and the Jira Agile REST API, so the authentication against both APIs seems to work. In JS I have tried with both fetch() and jquery ajax() and the result was the same.

```js
function fetchFromJira(url, id, token) {
  const authorizationString = 'Basic ' + btoa(id + ':' + token);
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: authorizationString,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        throw new Error(response.status);
      }
    })
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

fetchFromJira(
  'https://fredrikastrom.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/issue/10000',
  '<user id>',
  '<API token>'
); // successful

fetchFromJira(
  'https://fredrikastrom.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/board',
  '<user id>',
  '<API token>'
); // fails
```

The output onto the console looks as follows:

```
test.js:11 OPTIONS https://fredrikastrom.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/board 401 ()  
fetchFromJira @ test.js:11
(anonymous) @   test.js:33
index.html:1 Failed to load https://fredrikastrom.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/board: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401.
test.js:23 TypeError: Failed to fetch
test.js:20 {expand: "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations", id: "10000", self: "https://fredrikastrom.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/issue/10000", key: "FAT-1", fields: {…}}
```

Here are the preflight request and response headers of the successful query to the Jira REST API:

```
t=3241 [st= 89]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_HTTP2_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
                       --> :authority: fredrikastrom.atlassian.net
                           :method: OPTIONS
                           :path: /rest/api/latest/issue/10000
                           :scheme: https
                           accept: */*
                           accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
                           accept-language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,fi;q=0.6
                           access-control-request-headers: authorization,content-type
                           access-control-request-method: GET
                           cache-control: no-cache
                           origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
                           pragma: no-cache
                           referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/index.html
                           user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.62 Safari/537.36
t=3241 [st= 89]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=3241 [st= 89]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=68]
t=3278 [st=126]        HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                       --> delta = 0
                       --> stream_id = 1
                       --> window_size = 65535
t=3309 [st=157]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS
                       --> HTTP/1.1 200
                           status: 200
                           server: AtlassianProxy/1.15.8.1
                           vary: Accept-Encoding
                           cache-control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform
                           content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
                           content-encoding: gzip
                           strict-transport-security: max-age=315360000; includeSubDomains; preload
                           date: Sat, 12 Oct 2019 06:33:50 GMT
                           atl-traceid: 519aa518a8e8e5ea
                           x-arequestid: c68d7b95-3635-49e1-a2fd-971e0502adf5
                           x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
                           timing-allow-origin: *
                           x-content-type-options: nosniff
                           set-cookie: atlassian.xsrf.token=7a27221d-39bc-4555-9569-b26a0beb9689_b9e038120f5696c0bac7202f986ee24d3752c6fa_lout; Path=/; Secure
```

and here are the correspinding headers from the failing request to Jira Agile REST API:

```
t=5918 [st= 5]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_HTTP2_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
                      --> :authority: fredrikastrom.atlassian.net
                          :method: OPTIONS
                          :path: /rest/agile/latest/board
                          :scheme: https
                          accept: */*
                          accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
                          accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
                          access-control-request-headers: authorization,content-type
                          access-control-request-method: GET
                          origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
                          referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/index.html
                          user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.62 Safari/537.36
t=5919 [st= 6]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=5919 [st= 6]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=65]
t=5984 [st=71]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS
                      --> HTTP/1.1 401
                          status: 401
                          server: AtlassianProxy/1.15.8.1
                          vary: Accept
                          www-authenticate: OAuth realm="https%3A%2F%2Ffredrikastrom.atlassian.net"
                          cache-control: no-transform
                          content-type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
                          strict-transport-security: max-age=315360000; includeSubDomains; preload
                          date: Sat, 12 Oct 2019 07:05:10 GMT
                          atl-traceid: 2caf28fb1cce9a77
                          x-arequestid: 817e2b89-e3d1-431b-b892-781fc78c9669
                          x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
                          timing-allow-origin: *
                          x-content-type-options: nosniff
                          set-cookie: atlassian.xsrf.token=7a27221d-39bc-4555-9569-b26a0beb9689_dafc86c05dbdc472c9b99300b351fe0dd62b305d_lout; Path=/; Secure
                          content-length: 174
```

Interestingly, the request headers look slightly different even if the requests are made with the same function where only the requested URLs differ. The succeeding request includes the cache-control and pragma headers, and the accept-language header includes one more language. But none of these should reasonably have any impact on whether the server will accept the preflight request?

Any clue why the one request succeeds and the other one fails?

Comment: can you provide more information regarding the failure description?

Comment: Added the console output. So the output of console.log(error) is "TypeError: Failed to fetch". Was this useful? Is there some other information about the failure that I could provide?

Comment: Added preflight request and response headers, if that can be of some guidance.